# Passing data from the index file to a pug template in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, pug, pugjs

I started learning some NodeJs and want to create a small routing. So I use this code here for my server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/profile/:id', function (req, res) { // The URL for localhost:8888/profile/Peter

  var user = null; // Read some data from the JSON file later on...

  res.render('index', { // Load the index file and set some variables
    content: 'Views/profile.pug'
    name: user.name,
    hitpoints: user.hitpoints,
    stamina: user.stamina,
    strength: user.strength });
});

app.listen(8888, function () {
  console.log('Server listening on Port 8888');
});
```

So my index.pug file would handle the variables and uses `include` for the template to load

```
html

  link(rel='stylesheet', href='/CSS/requirements.css')
  script(src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js")

  body
    p 'TEST - This is on all pages'

    include content
```

So my template needs the user variables from the server

```
script(src="/Client/profile.js")

p 'Character:'
p = name

p 'Hitpoints:'
p = hitpoints

p 'Stamina:'
p = stamina

p 'Strength:'
p = strength

button(class='btn' onclick='back()') 'Back'
```

How can I get the information from the index.pug and send it to the template file the index.pug is including?

Like `include content // and pass the needed variables`

Comment: "get information from index.pug", so you want to send informations from index.pug to the server ? or do you mean, your pug template doesn't render the JSON values (var user) from the server ?

Comment: I just updated my post

Answer (score 0):

Rename your `index.pug` to `head.pug` and add as the first lines

```
doctype html
html
  head
    link(rel='styleshe...
```

Then replace your body part as such :

```
  body
    block content
```

now create a new file `profile.pug` and add as the first lines

```
extends head.pug
block content
  script(src="/Client/profile.js")

  p 'Character:'
```

and the rest of your template

In `server.js`, instead of rendering index.pug, render `profile.pug`

```
res.render('profile',
  name: user.name,
  hitpoints: user.hitpoints,
```

Comment: so when using `block` I can send the variables from the index file to the template files?

Comment: express will render your template with values from your `user` variable

Comment: hm are you sure? Normally I would have 1 index file and load some templates to it. Here you load the index to the template .. I don't know :/